# Why is this query missing a record when using the index?

Tags: mysql

MySQL started returning really weird results for a particular set of queries that use an index. What could have happened to the database to cause this? How do I fix it, and prevent this from happening again? This is just a local development database, but I'm concerned this could happen to production, which would be very bad.

MySQL 8.0.33 Homebrew (MacOS M1) InnoDB
Ruby on Rails 7.0.7, mysql2 0.5.5

This `team_game_stats` record with `game_id=19768` exists when queried independently.

```
SELECT id, game_id 
FROM team_game_stats 
WHERE game_id=19768 
AND category="passing" 
AND sub_category="attempts" 
AND team_id=3;

+---------+---------+
| id      | game_id |
+---------+---------+
| 6366235 |   19768 |
+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

When using `game_id` 19768 an `IN` query with other `game_ids`, the `team_game_stats` with `ID` 6366235, which was returned in the last query, is now missing!

```
mysql> SELECT id, game_id 
        from team_game_stats 
        WHERE game_id IN (19357, 19375, 19489, 19531, 19595, 19658, 19720, 19768, 19876, 19940, 20047, 20072, 22379) 
        AND category="passing" 
        AND sub_category="attempts" 
        AND team_id=3;

+---------+---------+
| id      | game_id |
+---------+---------+
| 6365296 |   19489 |
| 6365308 |   19357 |
| 6365546 |   19658 |
| 6365589 |   19531 |
| 6365810 |   19375 |
| 6365883 |   19720 |
| 6365950 |   19595 |
| 6366191 |   19876 |
| 6366460 |   19940 |
| 6366542 |   22379 |
| 6366596 |   20072 |
| 6366850 |   20047 |
+---------+---------+
12 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If I run the query and tell MySQL to ignore the game_id index `index_team_game_stats_on_game_id`, I get the missing record with `ID` 6366235.

```
mysql> select * 
        from team_game_stats 
        IGNORE INDEX (index_team_game_stats_on_game_id) 
        where game_id IN (19357, 19375, 19489, 19531, 19595, 19658, 19720, 19768, 19876, 19940, 20047, 20072, 22379) 
        AND category="passing" 
        AND sub_category="attempts" 
        AND team_id=3;
```

```
    | id      | category | sub_category | value  | box_score_id | game_id | team_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
    +---------+----------+--------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
    | 6365296 | passing  | attempts     | 20.000 |        31439 |   19489 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:02 | 2023-08-12 01:18:02 |
    | 6365308 | passing  | attempts     | 40.000 |        31440 |   19357 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:02 | 2023-08-12 01:18:02 |
    | 6365546 | passing  | attempts     | 19.000 |        31444 |   19658 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:04 | 2023-08-12 01:18:04 |
    | 6365589 | passing  | attempts     | 43.000 |        31441 |   19531 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:04 | 2023-08-12 01:18:04 |
    | 6365810 | passing  | attempts     | 39.000 |        31442 |   19375 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:06 | 2023-08-12 01:18:06 |
    | 6365883 | passing  | attempts     | 52.000 |        31445 |   19720 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:07 | 2023-08-12 01:18:07 |
    | 6365950 | passing  | attempts     | 22.000 |        31443 |   19595 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:07 | 2023-08-12 01:18:07 |
    | 6366191 | passing  | attempts     | 51.000 |        31448 |   19876 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:08 | 2023-08-12 01:18:08 |
    | 6366235 | passing  | attempts     | 37.000 |        31446 |   19768 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:09 | 2023-08-12 01:18:09 |
    | 6366460 | passing  | attempts     | 33.000 |        31447 |   19940 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:11 | 2023-08-12 01:18:11 |
    | 6366542 | passing  | attempts     | 22.000 |        31451 |   22379 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:12 | 2023-08-12 01:18:12 |
    | 6366596 | passing  | attempts     | 30.000 |        31450 |   20072 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:12 | 2023-08-12 01:18:12 |
    | 6366850 | passing  | attempts     | 30.000 |        31449 |   20047 |       3 | 2023-08-12 01:18:14 | 2023-08-12 01:18:14 |
    +---------+----------+--------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
    13 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Here's some general info about the table.

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE team_game_stats;
    
CREATE TABLE `team_game_stats` (
      `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `category` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `sub_category` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `value` decimal(7,3) DEFAULT NULL,
      `box_score_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
      `game_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
      `team_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
      `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `index_team_game_stats_on_box_score_id` (`box_score_id`),
      KEY `index_team_game_stats_on_game_id` (`game_id`),
      KEY `index_team_game_stats_on_team_id` (`team_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6366968 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci
```

Comment: I think it would be nice if you put up a SQLFiddle for this

Comment: Please include the full output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE team_game_stats;`, instead of `DESCRIBE`. You can try `ANALYZE TABLE team_game_stats;` to update the table stats or `ALTER TABLE team_game_stats ENGINE = InnoDB;` to rebuild the table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly is this the kind of thing you were looking for? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mPAj88WxVjpYwroBw1onNZ/0

Comment: Did you notice that row is NOT missing in the fiddle results!

Comment: Good job. Not relevant to this problem but [`utf8mb3` is deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html) and you should switch to `utf8mb4`. Did you try the other two suggestions. It would appear to be a specific issue with your index as it is not repeated in your fiddle.

Comment: Maybe the `index_team_game_stats_on_game_id` index is damaged. You could try dropping that index and then re-adding it

Comment: @user1191247 Thanks. I ran both `ANALYZE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE`, and I'm still seeing the same weird results posted in the example queries.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I removed all three indexes from the table and re-created them, but unfortunately, I'm still experiencing the same results as described in the examples above.

Comment: Getting desperate here! Did you try this on another PC

Comment: Are you able to share a full dump of the table so we can confirm not repeatable on another machine?

Comment: @user1191247 here's a link to a mysqldump of the table. It's pretty relatively large. Note that I deleted the affected records and created new ones, so the ids in team_game_stats are different. The behavior I'm seeing in this database is that ID 6367153 and 6367328 are missing unless you use the IGNORE INDEX query. Also in the query where you don't ignore the index, I'm seeing that ID 6367003 and 6367213 show up twice.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/s63tyk6t4fk0r1mea0wxt/tgs.sql.gz?rlkey=0if7slmxjcg3fu199tvor461d&dl=0

Comment: Tried this on a different machine with a fresh install of MySQL and reproduced the issue with the full table dump

Comment: Dropping the index fixed the issue, but recreating it creates the issue again.

Comment: I have loaded your data into MySQL Community Server 8.0.34 on both Windows Server 2022 (20348.1906) and Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS and cannot reproduce your issue. When you tried on another machine, was it another Mac?

Comment: @user1191247 thanks so much for trying. Yes it was another Mac.

Comment: My only other suggestion is to try MariaDB. It should require minimal changes, possibly none at all.

Comment: Thank you. I switched to using mysql in a docker container and that seems to be working.